# Should copying the copyMaterialsSet work in script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-classroom

Should this function work inside Google Apps Script? Do I have to do anything to the object before passing it back to update?

```
function copyMaterialSet() {

   var courseOne = Classroom.Courses.get("16XXXXXXXX");
   // Logger.log(courseOne);

   var courseTwo = Classroom.Courses.get("46XXXXXXXX");
    //Logger.log(courseTwo);

   courseTwo.courseMaterialSets = courseOne.courseMaterialSets;
    //Logger.log(courseTwo);

    var update = Classroom.Courses.update(courseTwo, "46XXXXXXXX");

    //Did it update?
    var courseUpdated = Classroom.Courses.get("46XXXXXXXX");
    Logger.log(courseUpdated);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this a bug. I've tested both Apps Script and Classroom API but didn't get an update regarding courseMaterialSet. You can file an [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823907)  on this with all the details you've encountered then post the link here for future readers.

Comment: The issue has been reported at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62386725